# Community Take over project

Tags: metadata

i have a question about about changing Metadata to another Token who is not mine . Can i change the Metadata , or just the creator of that token.We are Community Take over and we want to update logo ,Tg etc....

Thanks I am waiting for a reply

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update the logo, name, or other metadata on a token, you must have the mint authority of said token. Otherwise you will not be able to update the token metadata.